# Why prefix a method with "self"

Tags: ruby, self

I'm doing the following Ruby Tutorial
http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/48-advanced-modules/lessons/118-wrapping-up-modules

One of the exercises asks me to

> ...define a static method square in the module Math. It should obviously return the square of the number passed to it...

Why does it only work when I prefix the method definition with "self"? E.g. the following works:

```
module Math
  def self.square(x)
    x ** 2
  end
end
```

But the following does NOT work:

```
module Math
  def square(x)
    x ** 2
  end
end
```

Why is this? For reference, the method is being called like `puts Math.square(6)`

Comment: see [ruby definition of self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873889/ruby-definition-of-self?rq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the context of a module, declaring a method with `self` as a prefix makes it a module method, one that can be called without having to `include` or `extend` with the module.

If you'd like to have mix-in methods, which is the default, and module methods, which requires the `self` prefix, you can do this:

```
module Math
  # Define a mix-in method
  def square(x)
    x ** 2
  end

  # Make all mix-in methods available directly
  extend self
end
```

That should have the effect of making these methods usable by calling `Math.square` directly.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly, declaring without "self" would force me to use a mixin like include or extend wherever I want to use it... Whereas declaring with "self" will allow me to call it like MyModule.MyMethod ?

Comment: Exactly. A similar sort of thing plays out with classes, only instead of `include` and `extend`, you inherit.

Answer (score 0):

In method definition, if you do not have `self.`, then it is defined on an instance of that class. Since `Math` is not an instance of `Math`, it will not work without it.