# What are the differences between 'self' in ruby and 'this' in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby

I am familiar with ruby and begin to learn javascript. Is it safe to skip to learn 'this' and consider it as a complete equivalence of ruby's 'self' in javascript and 'apply' in javascript is the same as 'instance_eval' in ruby?

If not,what are some big differences between them?

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment since I'm not going into detail on the full differences, but you need to learn 'this' in JavaScript.  It is treated unlike Ruby's `self` and for that matter unlike `this` or `self` equivalents in most other languages.  JavaScript uses a lexical scoping with some fairly complex rules as to how scope is created; defaults vs explicit binding etc... Take a look at the official documentation here for starters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: When you use self as part of a [class method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) definition it you are creating a class method. ie. `def self.foo ... end `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` is widely used in [Ruby Metaprogramming](http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/).

From [Metaprogramming Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476) book:

> Every line of Ruby code is executed inside an object—the so–called
>   current object. The current object is also known as self, because
>   you can access it with the self keyword.
>
> Only one object can take the role of self at a given time, but no
>   object holds that role for a long time. In particular, when you call a
>   method, the receiver becomes self. From that moment on, all instance
>   variables are instance variables of self, and all methods called
>   without an explicit receiver are called on self. As soon as your code
>   explicitly calls a method on some other object, that other object
>   becomes self.

For example:

```
class Foo

  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name  
  end

  # here self indicates the class itself Foo
  def self.bar
  end

  # here self indicates the instance of class Foo
  def baz
    self.name
  end
end
```

Now:

```
foo = Foo.new('FooBar')
foo.baz #=> 'FooBar'
```

While in JavaScript use of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword is powerful and unique, it does not refer to an object(as of ES5's strict mode) like Ruby as shown above. `this` can have any value. The value of `this` within any given function call is determined by how the function is called (not where the function is defined, i.e. the context, as in languages like Ruby, C#, or Java). But, similar to Ruby's `self`, `this` can't be set by assignment during execution. For example:

Global context([directly copied from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)):

```
console.log(this.document === document); // true

// In web browsers, the window object is also the global object:
console.log(this === window); // true

this.a = 37;
console.log(window.a); // 37
```

or as an object method:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = function() {
  console.log(this.firstName);
};
foo.firstName = 'FooBar';
foo.bar(); // "FooBar"
```

From examples shown it's pretty clear that JavaScript's `this` isn't exactly a cousin brother of Ruby's `self`, but do they have a small pinch of similarity in their behaviors.

For exploring Ruby's `self` further [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873889/ruby-definition-of-self) and for JavaScript's `this` [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's 'this' value can be changed to anything, by default 'this' references the immediate parent. (so a function in the global scope will reference the window object.)

This is an arbitrary example but should show the idea well enough. When you call a function such as myFunc() it is a shortcut for saying myFunc.call(). The first argument that .call() accepts is the value for 'this'.

Look here to see more on call:
https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}

foo(); // this will log out the window object

var bar = {
  fname: 'Edy',
  sayHello: function() {
    alert('Hello ' + this.fname);
  },
  baz: function() {
   console.log(this);
  }
}

bar.baz(); // will log out the 'bar' object

var person = {
  fname: 'Danny'
}

var person2 = {
  fname: 'Elenore'
}

function sayHello() {
    alert('Hello ' + this.fname);
}

sayHello.call(person); // will alert 'Danny'
sayHello.call(person2); // will alert 'Elenore'
```

Comment: To clarify - `this = {}` is not valid in JS, so you can not change `this` by assignment. However, `this` can be *supplied* for any given run of an function/method: `f = function(){ console.log(this); }; f.call({}) /* <= supply a value for 'this' */`